# OnScreen keyboard doesn't register key presses in lock screen with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, keyboard, lock-screen, 22.04, onscreen-keyboard

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 the OnScreen keyboard that's shipped with Gnome does not work anymore for me to enter the password on the lock screen with the Surface Go 1 tablet. This is only the lock screen (pink-ish background), on the log-in screen (gray background) and when the screen is unlocked it works normally. On the lock screen I can swipe up the OnScreen keyboard, but it doesn't register any input. When I open the log-in screen (change user button on the lower right) I can use the on screen keyboard normally to enter my password and log back in to my session.

This has worked in Ubuntu 21.10.

Has anyone experienced the same issue and knows how to get key presses registered on the lock screen? Or alternatively disable the lock screen altogether and only have the log-in screen in its place?

Hardware: Surface Go 1 tablet
Software: Ubuntu 22.04, Gnome OnScreen Keyboard

tl;dr: OnScreen keyboard is there on lock screen, but doesn't register input. It does register input on the log-in screen.

Comment: Thanks to /u/rinspeed on Reddit we now have an issue open for this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1973386 - if you are affected please consider adding yourself to affected users and follow this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in Gnome 42.1, which rolled out to Ubuntu 22.04 a couple of days ago. OSK now works on the lock screen and in password fields.

If you have this problem update your installation (sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade) and it should work.